# How to set up an alarm in a MVC app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to implement a function that when a to-do item is due, the server gives some sort of alert or notification to the specific client.

In order to achieve that function, the task is broken down to two parts, One is pushing alerts, and second is how to schedule an alarm for the to-do item.

I have done some research, and so far everything is pointing to using SignalR for sending notification. Is there any other easy way of achieving this?

And for scheduling an alarm, Timer class is not appropriate. And there is not much information in stackoverflow.

Any advice that gives me the direction is appreciated.

Comment: `when a to-do item is due,` What is an interval that server want to communicate with client browser?

Comment: Like right away? whenever the expiry datetime is due, the server gives the alert. I don't need to worry about saving that alert until next time the client logs in.

Comment: Just to make it clear. Do you need to send notification to the client whatever you want, even if they are not browsing your web application inside their browser?

Comment: No, just push notification when they are browsing my web application. If they are not browsing the app at the time the alert is sent, then just ignore.

Comment: Then you want to use SignalR.

Answer (score 4):

SignalR is supereasy to setup, especially as you are already using ASP.NET MVC. How much easier do you want it? You can program you own webhooks, but as SignalR takes care of all the communication fluf, setting up the connection for you and supporting all communication models from webhooks to long polling, which would allow you to target almost any browser, why would you want to use anything else...

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Now I realize I can't even schedule an alarm properly. Do you have any insight on that?

Comment: @oopsdazie You could use a `System.Threading.Timer` for that.